# Express $\int_A^Bfdg$ as a sum using $\sigma_n$ and $\sum_{i=0}^ns_i$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

**Question**

> Let $\{s_n\},\{\sigma_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ be monotone increasing and are able to be summed. Also let $\{u_n\},\{v_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $A < u_i < v_i < u_{i+1} < B$ for all $i$. Let $H$ denote the Heaviside function and suppose that
>   $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n H(x-u_n)$$ and $$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sigma_n H(x-v_n).$$
>   Express $\int_A^Bfdg$ as a sum using $\sigma_n$ and $\sum_{i=0}^ns_i$.

**Attempt**

I know we can break down the integral and interchange the sum and integral to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_A^B s_n H(x-u_n)dg.$$
I'm trying to understand how to eliminate one of the Heaviside functions although it's not immediately clear if that's possible and how to achieve $\sum_{i=0}^ns_i$ in the final form.

Comment: What do you mean by "able to be summed?" Do you mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n$ converges? If so, that, along with $s_n$ monotone increasing would require $s_n<0$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that it is summable. Yes, that the sum you state converges.

Comment: So $s_n$ and $\sigma_n$ are negative? Or did you want monotone decreasing?

Comment: I believe $s_n$ and $\sigma_n$ must be negative, as you say.